# Mongodb no route to host while running mongo on a local machine

Tags: mongodb

I have installed MongoDB on a local machine by following [this](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/tutorial/install-mongodb-on-ubuntu/) tutorial and [this](http://tecadmin.net/install-mongodb-on-ubuntu/#) one as well. I used my local user (using sudo in all commands) and then I do:

```
sudo service mongod start
```

It says `start: Job is already running: mongod`. Then when I run this command

> sudo mongo

I get

> MongoDB shell version: 2.6.0
>   connecting to: test
>   2014-07-08T12:33:40.360+0200 warning: Failed to connect to 127.0.0.1:27017, reason: errno:113 No route to host
>   2014-07-08T12:33:40.361+0200 Error: couldn't connect to server 127.0.0.1:27017 (127.0.0.1), connection attempt failed at src/mongo/shell/mongo.js:146
>   exception: connect failed

THis is also the output of `netstat -tpln`

```
(No info could be read for "-p": geteuid()=1000 but you should be root.)
Active Internet connections (only servers)
Proto Recv-Q Send-Q Local Address           Foreign Address         State       PID/Program name
tcp 

   0      0 0.0.0.0:27017           0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      -
```

Also this is the output of  `sudo /sbin/iptables -L -n`

```
Chain INPUT (policy DROP)
target     prot opt source               destination
ACCEPT     tcp  --  0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0            state NEW tcp dpt:22
ACCEPT     tcp  --  0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0            state NEW tcp dpt:80
ACCEPT     tcp  --  0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0            state NEW tcp dpt:5432
ACCEPT     tcp  --  0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0            state NEW tcp dpt:8080
ACCEPT     tcp  --  0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0            state NEW tcp dpt:8443
ACCEPT     tcp  --  0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0            state NEW tcp dpt:3306
ACCEPT     icmp --  0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0            icmptype 255
ACCEPT     all  --  0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0            state RELATED,ESTABLISHED
REJECT     all  --  0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0            reject-with icmp-host-prohibited
ACCEPT     tcp  --  127.0.0.1            0.0.0.0/0            tcp dpt:27017 state NEW,ESTABLISHED
ACCEPT     tcp  --  127.0.0.1            0.0.0.0/0            tcp dpt:27017 state NEW,ESTABLISHED
ACCEPT     tcp  --  127.0.0.1            0.0.0.0/0            tcp dpt:27017 state NEW,ESTABLISHED

Chain FORWARD (policy ACCEPT)
target     prot opt source               destination

Chain OUTPUT (policy ACCEPT)
target     prot opt source               destination
ACCEPT     tcp  --  0.0.0.0/0            127.0.0.1            tcp spt:27017 state ESTABLISHED
ACCEPT     tcp  --  0.0.0.0/0            127.0.0.1            tcp spt:27017 state ESTABLISHED
ACCEPT     tcp  --  0.0.0.0/0            127.0.0.1            tcp spt:27017 state ESTABLISHED
```

I have followed several proposed solutions and never worked. Any suggestions?

I have followed several proposed solutions and never worked. Any suggestions?

Comment: First of all, you shouldn't need `sudo` to use mongo. Please add the output of `netstat -tpln` to your question.

Comment: @M-T-A have you tried `mongo localhost:27017`?

Comment: @naimdjon yes and it is not working too :(

Comment: @xlembouras I have added that too. Please have a look.

Comment: try losing the `sudo`.

Comment: @xlembouras I ran `mongo` with no sudo and I get the same error.

Comment: @M-T-A  sounds like firewall issue. Try disabling it and check if it works. BTW, what is the output of `/sbin/iptables -L -n`?

Comment: @naimdjon I have updated the question, please have a look.

Comment: @M-T-A disable firewall and try it. `service iptables stop`, if ubuntu: `sudo ufw disable`.

Comment: @naimdjon I got exactly the same error.

Comment: You have to get rid of the rule `REJECT     all  --  0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0            reject-with icmp-host-prohibited`. The mongod process is there listening to 27017 but you need to get rid of that firewall rule.

Comment: @naimdjon If I disable the firewall, doesn't that mean that this rule is not applied?

Comment: @M-T-A If you disable you should see something like this:
```
Chain INPUT (policy ACCEPT)
target     prot opt source               destination         

Chain FORWARD (policy ACCEPT)
target     prot opt source               destination         

Chain OUTPUT (policy ACCEPT)
target     prot opt source               destination```

Comment: Disabling iptables and ufw in ubuntu solved this issue. Please make an answer to select it as an answer. @naimdjon

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is most likely a firewall issue in your distro. Based on the output from `iptables` the mongod process is there listening to `27017` port but you need to get rid of this firewall rule:

```
REJECT     all  --  0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0            reject-with icmp-host-prohibited
```

This seems to cause of the problem. To find out about it, flush the rules in  `iptables` (`-F`) and/or disabling `ufw` in ubuntu may solve the issue.

Comment: i had a problem with remote connection to mongodb .This hint solved my problem it was due to firewall problem